# NPCs becoming PCs

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, character-advancement

I am running the *Rage of Demons* D&D 5e campaign and there is a serious possibility that one of my players decides to take over one of the NPCs. How do I handle character progression in case of such "unusual" races?

The campaign features very interesting NPCs (SPOILER) that make sense in this setting. For example, A Kuo-toa, a Myconid, Quaggoths and Wererats - these are the troublesome cases - deep gnomes for example can be handled with relative ease.

My rule of thumb would be to equate Hit Dice to levels, and let then progress normally with classes afterwards. This, however, doesn't factor special abilities. In previous edition we had templates, and effective character level, but not in 5e.

For example, a Quaggoth has 6d8 average. If I hand it over to a PC, does he start as a 1st level (say) fighter, adding 1d10hp to his already high score and getting to 2nd level with an handful of XP? Or do I consider him as a 6-level PC, so he needs a large amount of XP to get his new level.

Suggestions?

Comment: I understand the general question but I'm having a hard time identifying the exact problem you face with regards to allowing a player to take control of an NPC.  What is the exact problem you are trying to solve?  More detail in that regard will help improve the quality of answers you receive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This depends on whether the PC will be taking over the NPC temporarily (say for one or two sessions) or if they will be taking it over permanently.

### If it's temporary just use the NPC stats.

In 5e I once had a new joining player who had no previous pen-and-paper experience play a simple NPC character for his first couple sessions. This worked really well as the mechanics for an NPC are far simpler, they've got a ton of HP so don't die to simple tactical mistakes, and the player could still get used to RPing. In our case the player used a Veteran (MM p. 350) npc and the power was about on par with 4th level party.

After a couple sessions the player was sure they wanted to continue playing with us and the party was near a level up. He really liked his character and wanted to continue playing it but...

### If it's permanent, remake the NPC using PC classes

...NPC's don't really work like PC's. The DMG has a great chart (p. 274) for how AC, HP, Attack, and damage are supposed to map to the CR of an NPC. You'll notice it doesn't have any concept of hit dice since, for an NPC, they don't matter. An NPC has as many hit points as are required for it to meet the CR it was designed for. Similarly an NPC's access to spells is gated based on how much impact a particular spell has rather than the level of the spell. This makes it rather fiddly to figure out how much (and it what ways) to power up the NPC when it levels.

Next problem is that NPC's are no where near as flexible as PC's. Flipping through the monster manual you can quickly see that monsters tend to be good at one or two things with no skills at all outside of those areas. Even high level NPCs like the Archmage (MM. 342) have two proficient skills and that's it. PC's on the other hand often start with more proficiency than an NPC will ever have, and then accumulate lots of minor options as they level up. This means that where PC's have a variety of approaches to solve a problem an NPC will tend to be stuck with one approach regardless of the situation.

The way we avoided these problems was to just remake the NPC using PC classes. There's not much an NPC is capable of where you can't get the same feel with the PC classes. In our case Fighter with Champion archetype felt very much like the Veteran NPC had so it was an easy conversion. The HP dropped significantly which the player had to get use to, but it also meant they now had way more options available and were much more valuable to the party. I suggest taking a similar approach.

While I haven't converted a more exotic NPC to a PC class I have DM'd for a PC playing a Myconid. We used Dwarf stat bonuses as a base, gave him sun sickness and spores from the myconid NPC entry, and it worked well. For other exotic races you'll need to do some similar ad-hoc adding of abilities to make the conversion feel right. However, I'm confident that it will much easier to accomplish these than it would be to balance full NPC style stats as the character grows.

Comment: The takeover should be permanent. I am well aware of differences between NPCs and PCs - I have a long DM carreer. So you say, my Myconid should become a 2nd level fighter (same stats, same hp as the monster), and then let him grow normally?  In some cases it might work, but probably Wererats are more problematic.

Comment: The wererat might work with minor alterations to one of the Shifter races from Unearthed Arcana, or else a dip into Druid to pick up the ability to turn into a rat.

Comment: @Piffy The Myconid should be a level that fits with the parties current level, and a class or classes that provide abilities matching up with what the npc had before. If the NPC was mostly a brawler that could be fighter, but it could also be Barbarian with rage refluffed as fungal trance, or Monk with one of the more physical paths. The exact conversion is going to be very subjective as you're trying to maintain the feel of the NPC rather than particular stats.

Answer (score 3):

**Simply Build a Custom Race**

...then apply whichever class desired by the player, perhaps bearing in mind how that NPC has behaved in the campaign until now.

As an answer, it might sound a little trite, but it isn't as hard as it seems. There are several examples in *Volo's Guide* and elsewhere which you can use as reference for creating playable monstrous races. Use the Monster Manual entries and NPC descriptions for inspiration.

Creating a new race is one of the easiest pieces of design you can undertake in 5E because there are so many examples to balance against. It's the work of just a few minutes.

It should certainly be deployed to your table with the caveat that it might need to be tweaked during play, however.

By insisting on a race/class combo, you make your job even easier. Derendil might have to be a barbarian, Ront a fighter, JimJar a rogue, and Stool...well, good luck with that one. :)

Comment: The problems are the "exisisting" hit points, skills and bonuses. I might make sense to say that thei only the higher bonus possible (Ront might get more it points only pas 3-4° level, for example).

Comment: In our game Stool was a non-combatant who just cowered whenever a fight broke out.